# Why is <algorithm> not needed for std::copy or std::swap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

According to this [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) page, `std::copy` is in the `<algorithm>` header, as is `std::swap` and yet this works:

```
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <vector>  // std::vector
#include <iterator>  // std::ostream_iterator()
#include <cstdlib>  // rand(), srand()

// NOT including <algorithm>

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  const int SIZE = 10;
  std::vector<int> vec; 

  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  {
     vec.push_back(rand() % 256);
  }

  copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The only thing I could think of is that they are exported by `<vector>` as well...but then why do we need the `<algorithm>` header at all?

Comment: `<algorithm>` (and `<utility>` for `std::swap` in C++11) *are* needed. Other headers might include them, but you cannot rely on that.

Comment: At least, you *shouldn't* rely on that.  But yeah, look at your other includes.  They are pulling in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Related pointless trivia: while the C++ standard allows one standard header to include another, that isn't permitted by the C standard.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Does that mean that if a standard header uses `NULL`, it must define it (in the header) rather than include stddef.h/stdlib.h/etc? And that it must forward declare needed functions from other headers rather than include those headers? Or is it even more stringent than that?

Comment: @Cornstalks: in C a standard header wouldn't typically need to *use* a definition of `NULL`; there are seven headers that need to define it. Similarly with forward declarations of functions - those aren't needed in the headers (as far as I know).  Some typedefs, like `size_t`, are declared in more than one header; an implementation will typically use a macro with a reserved name to prevent redeclaring the typedef for when a user includes more than one of those headers.

Comment: @Cornstalks: An implementation might also include a common, non-standard, header that's implementation specific from more than one standard header. However, those headers would not be permitted to declare global or macro names that are not reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Any C implementation is free to define `_NULL` anywhere it likes (since _ is a reserved prefix). There's no reason why a standard header would ever be forced to #define `NULL` for internal use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The particular implementation of `<vector>` that you're using here probably includes definitions for `copy` and `swap` (possibly by including `<algorithm>`, or possibly by including some other private header that contains them), but that's just an implementation detail and isn't guaranteed to be portable. It's entirely possible that if you were to switch compilers, you'd end up using an implementation of the C++ standard libraries where `copy` and `swap` weren't imported by `<vector>`, in which case your code will no longer compile.

In other words, just because it happens to work on your compiler doesn't mean it's portable, so for maximum portability and correctness you should include `<algorithm>` anyway.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't necessarily include `<algorithm>`. `std::copy` may be defined in another file which is included by both `<algorithm>` and `<vector>`.

Answer (score 1):

"exported by `<vector>`"...

In C++, things aren't *exported*.

But yeah, `<vector>` is allowed to `#include <algorithm>`, which means you get access to all of `<algorithm>` when you use `<vector>`. But to be safe, you should still `#include <algorithm>` yourself, as a different implementation (or even a different version) may not do this, and if you don't include it yourself it could break your code.

Comment: What's the correct verbiage for this?  I guess export is more of a Java thing?

Comment: @David: It would be better to say "`<algorithm>` might be included by `<vector>`", but if you're talking about the functions `std::copy` and `std::swap` (rather than the whole `<algorithm>` header), I might say something like "declarations for `std::swap` and `std::copy` might be (indirectly) included in `<vector>`".

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `<vector>` in the Clang Standard C++ library includes `<algorithm>`.  Notably, `std::vector<T>` has a `swap()` method, so this might be a clue why.

Remember that algorithms in `<algorithm>` work, in many cases, on iterators, and that pointers are often interchangeable.  It's perfectly feasible to be using the algorithms contained within on data structures that are not STL containers.